# Finite automata for any even number of a's followed by any even number of b's

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I'm new to formal languages. I'm stuck with the following question. Any help is appreciated.

Find finite automata for

> $$L = \{a^i b^j \mid i, j\text{ are even, }j\ge0\}$$

Thank you

Comment: Isn't $j\geq 0$ assumed - in languages, $a^ib^j$ always means $i,j\geq 0$. Or maybe you meant $j>0$?

Comment: Yeah, it is assumed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Your language is $(aa)^*(bb)^*$. Now you may apply standard algorithms to get a finite automaton accepting $L$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by making a FA to accept the $a$s: you'll need two states, the start state will be a final state and the other won't be final. Then make another FA to handle the $b$s: you'll need a machine similar to the first one. Then link your first FA to the second with an appropriate transition on input $b$. Finally, figure out which of the states of the second machine need to be final.

When you cover nondeterministic finite automata, you'll see a general construction for such critters, since your language can be written as the concatenation, $L_1L_2$, of two simpler languages,

$$
L_1=\{a^i\mid i\text{ even, } i\ge 0\}\quad L_2=\{b^i\mid i\text{ even, } i\ge 0\}
$$